# Grouping WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, where-clause

I’m attempting to write a query that does the following.

Return all values in the current FQ that are 0 and return all values last FQ that weren’t 0

I’m wondering if there is a way to group WHERE clauses.

Essentially I want to do this in a single WHERE clause:

```
  WHERE date = 3/31/2019 AND value != 0
  OR
  WHERE date = 6/30/2019 AND value = 0
```

I’d like it to evaluate the 3/31/2019 AND Value != 0 as one clause then use OR to have it evaluate the other clause.

Is this possible in a single query?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Sure you can. Just use correct syntax for date literals.

Comment: `WHERE (date = '2019-03-31' AND VALUE <> 0) OR (date = '2019-06-30' and VALUE = 0)` should work. It's hard to say for certain, because you've not posted sample data, the results you'd like to get from that data, and an actual complete query that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'm writing this on My SQL server. It kept moving my parentheses, that's what was making me think SQL didn't like what Ken White posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL query has only one `where` clause.  This can consist of arbitrary combinations of `AND` and `OR`.  Your clause can be written as:

```
WHERE date = '2019-03-31' AND value <> 0 OR
      date = '2019-06-30' AND value = 0
```

This works because the `AND` binds more tightly than the `OR` (i.e. it has higher precedence).  However, parentheses would often be used for this:

```
WHERE (date = '2019-03-31' AND value <> 0) OR
      (date = '2019-06-30' AND value = 0)
```

Note the use of the ISO standard date format.  This is the preferred format in most databases.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the great explanation! I will have to take a deeper dive into the precedence of these conditions.